# Newbie Question: in Blender 2.8 Adding Armature options missing?

Tags: armature

I did try searching for this but didn't find anything.

I've been following some tutorials for Rigging and have seen a lot of videos showing  Armature Templates available from the Armature sub option see attached. 
On the version of blender I'm using 2.8 Beta Win 10 64 bit (23 April 19) I have no options to select anything. 
Only the Armature menu heading is from the ADD option  which when selected provides a single bone.

Have these other options gone now or do I need to configure something within blender?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You need to enable Rigify to see them.

1. Click on "Edit" -> "Preferences..."
2. In the new window, click on "Add-ons"
3. In the search bar at the top right, type in 'rig'
4. You should now see "Rigging: Rigify"
5. Click the checkbox next to it and close the window; now you should see those extra options

Note: I ran into the same problem; this solution was based on help from the Gabbitt 3D Discord channel.

Comment: Nice one thanks :-)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is the actual answer, ty bro, you helped a lot =)